# Replicating scmpoo, the stray sheep

Tags: c++, screen

I decided to replicate scmpoo, you might have used that on your old computer, but it's incompatible with any newer version, so I decided to remake it.

The first problem is that I haven't figured out how to draw the sheep on the screen. It's like my own screen is out of my reach D:

I tried making a window with an image inside, but I don't know how to make the window transparent wile keeping the image visible? Any ideas? I'm sure this is possible somehow.

I have some experience with windows.h but don't know if I could use it for this?

Also the original sheep could stand on windows and taskbar, so I'll need a way to get the positions of them too.

Is there maybe a way to access other windows and draw the sheep in them? (primarily talking about desktop) also if I could access other windows I could get their positions.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using GDI+ in a Win32 environment, you need to pay attention to some points:

- Transparency of the layered window while visualizing your image can be achieved with [UpdateLayeredWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633556(v=vs.85).aspx) (assuming your image is in the selected HBITMAP)
- Use a [layered window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599(v=vs.85).aspx#layered) for smooth graphic redrawing

That should give you a good starting point to implement your screenmate. In order to fiddle with existing windows and/or their sizes use [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx).

References: [splash screen with GDI+](http://code.logos.com/blog/2008/09/displaying_a_splash_screen_with_c_introduction.html)

---

Edit: since you decided in the comments to go for CSplash, in order to change positions to the splash screens you should modify the window position

```
    DWORD nScrWidth  = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFULLSCREEN);
    DWORD nScrHeight = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFULLSCREEN);

    int x = (nScrWidth  - m_dwWidth) / 2; // Center horizontally
    int y = (nScrHeight - m_dwHeight) / 2; // Center vertically
    m_hwnd = ::CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST|WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW, m_lpszClassName, 
                              TEXT("Banner"), WS_POPUP, x, y, 
                              m_dwWidth, m_dwHeight, NULL, NULL, NULL, this);
```

Comment: Just to let you know how I solwed the last of the library problems..I decided to look into the library again and in 5min I realized that when calling 'RegisterClassEx' function all of my classes had the same, default, classname. Changing that allowed me to show as many of them as I need :)